# Finding eigen(values/vectors) of a specific matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having trouble with a French test, which seems to have errors.

The final aim is to find the eigenvalues of the matrix $A_n$(and its eigenvectors):
$$A_7 = \begin{bmatrix}
0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0 \\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1 \\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
To do so, however, the test forces us to answer some questions.
It sets up a sequence called $u_n$:
$$
    u_n = \det(2\cos(α) * I_n - A_n)
$$

The polynomial expression of the matrix evaluated at $2\cos(α)$; with $α$ in $(0, \pi)$:
$$
    2\cos(α) * I_n - A_n = \begin{bmatrix}
     2\cos(α)&      -1&       0& \dots&  0&       0&       0 \\
           -1& 2\cos(α)&      -1& \dots&  0&       0&       0 \\
            0&      -1& 2\cos(α)& ...&  0&       0&       0 \\
          \vdots&     \vdots&        & \ddots&   &        &         \\
            0&       0&       0& ...& -1& 2\cos(α)&      -1 \\
            0&       0&       0& ...&  0&      -1& 2\cos(α) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Also seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liXx8.png)

The first question asks to set up a relation between $u_n$, $u_{n-1}$, $u_{n-2}$.
I found
    $$u_n = 2\cos(\alpha) * u_{n-1} - u_{n-2}$$

and checked that it does work for $n = 4$.

The second question asks us to deduce that

$$u_n = \frac{\sin(n+1)\alpha}{\sin(\alpha)}$$

This is where I think the mistake is, as
$$
u_2 = 4\cos(\alpha)^2 - 1 \neq \frac{\sin(3)\alpha}{\sin(α)} \text{ for } \alpha \in (0, \pi)
$$
I've found that this relation does hold true for $α = 1$, and possibly for $α = 2.2$, but not for other angles.

That is the biggest issue I've encountered, and is the main problem of this question.

The third question asks us to deduce the eigenvalue from the previous results, and the fourth asks for all of the eigenvectors associated with those values.

You can find the original test, in French, here (see page 3, section I-B):

https://www.concours-centrale-supelec.fr/CentraleSupelec/2015/TSI/sujets/2014-021.pdf

Comment: No idea about your question but the eigenvalues / eigenvectors of $A_n$ have the form 

$$\lambda_k = 2\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\quad\text{ and }\quad
v_k \propto \left(\sin\frac{k\pi}{n+1},\sin\frac{2k\pi}{n+1},\cdots,\sin\frac{nk\pi}{n+1}\right)^T$$
for $k = 1,\ldots,n$. There should be a name for this matrix but I can't remember...

Comment: @achillehui thanks! The test calls it a "tridiagonal" matrix, though I translated from French.

Comment: It is a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix. It is nicer than a usual tridiagonal matrix because the Toeplitz structure makes the coefficients in the recurrence relation constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol $\sin(n+1)\alpha$ means $\sin\left((n+1)\alpha\right)$, not $\left(\sin(n+1)\right)\alpha$.

Comment: Oh my god, this is the equivalent of forgetting a semicolon in programming...
I just tested, and sure enough, that relation is true...

Comment: I might be interesting to add _why_ the implicit parentheses are like this. symbols like $\sin,\cos,\log,\exp$, although they represent functions, are not treated syntactically like $f$ in $f(x)$ (since then parentheses around the argument would be obligatory) but rather as "large operators" like $\sum,\int,\lim,\bigcap$. These large operators bind to the right less strongly than multiplication (whether or not with an explicit operator), but stronger than `$+$' or $-$. So in $\sin(x+\frac\pi2)$, one cannot omit the parentheses. (Binding to the left poses no ambiguity; $2\sin x$ is fine.)